# How do I sub sample data by group using ddply?

Tags: r, plyr

I've got a data frame with far too many rows to be able to do a spatial correlogram. Instead, I want to grab 40 rows for each species and run my correlogram on that subset.

I wrote a function to subset a data frame as follows:

```
    samp <- function(dataf)
{
    dataf[sample(1:dim(dataf)[1], size=40, replace=FALSE),]
}
```

Now I want to apply this function to each species in a larger data frame.

When I try something like

```
culled_data = ddply (larger_data, .(species), subset, samp)
```

I get this error:

```
Error in subset.data.frame(piece, ...) : 
  'subset' must evaluate to logical
```

Anyone got ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like it should work once you remove `, subset` from your call.

Comment: Thanks Dirk. That did it. Perhaps someone could explain how else subset would work in ddply.

Comment: Dunno -- You could subset your data as in `ddply(larger_data[subset,], .(species), samp)` or maybe via `subset()`.

Answer (score 6):

Dirk answer is of course correct, but to add additional explanation I post my own.

#### Why your call don't work?

First of all your syntax is a shorthand. It's equivalent of

```
ddply(larger_data, .(species), function(dfrm) subset(dfrm, samp))
```

so you can clearly see that you provide `function` (see `class(samp)`) as second argument of `subset`. You could use `samp(dfrm)`, but it won't work too cause `samp` return `data.frame` and `subset` need logical vector. So you could use `samp(dfrm)` when it returns logical indexing.

#### How to use subset in this case?

Make `subset` work by feed him with logical vector:

```
ddply (larger_data, .(species), subset, sample(seq_along(species)<=40))
```

I create logical vector with 40 `TRUE` (btw it works when for some spieces is less then 40 cases, then it return all) and random it.

Comment: I do not thing this like does what it is supposed to do! ddply (larger_data, .(species), subset, sample(seq_along(species)<=40))

Comment: @Mark It supposed to select randomly 40 cases from each species. It's not working for you?