# Taking a disproportionate sample from a dataset in R

Tags: r, random, sampling

If I have a large dataset in R, how can I take random sample of the data taking into consideration the distribution of the original data, particularly if the data are skewed and only 1% belong to a minor class and I want to take a biased sample of the data?

Comment: Import the data, find the weights for your "levels" and let `sample` take care of the rest. It would help if you could narrow your question down (with at least sample data - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923092/how-do-i-sub-sample-data-by-group-using-ddply

Answer (score 22):

The `sample(x, n, replace = FALSE, prob = NULL)` function takes a sample from a vector `x` of size `n`. This sample can be **with** or **without replacement**, and the probabilities of selecting each element to the sample can be either **the same for each element**, or **a vector** informed by the user.

If you want to take a sample of same probabilities for each element with 50 cases, all you have to do is

```
n <- 50
smpl <- df[sample(nrow(df), 50),]
```

However, if you want to give different probabilities of being selected for the elements, let's say, elements that **sex** is **M** has probability **0.25**, while those whose **sex** is **F** has prob **0.75**, you should do

```
n <- 50
prb <- ifelse(sex=="M",0.25,0.75)
smpl <- df[sample(nrow(df), 50, prob = prb),]
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something obvious here, I'm getting `Error in ifelse(sex == "M", 0.25, 0.75) : object 'sex' not found` from trying to run the last example.

Comment: I did just get it to work with `prob=ifelse(df$sex == "M", 0.25, 0.75)` in the `sample` function, though.